# Permisos android studio (pantalla blanca)

Tags: android, permisos

Tengo un problema con mi aplicación ya que al ingresar a la misma por primera vez pido permisos de cámara y geolocalización pero al aceptarlas o no la pantalla queda en blanco y queda como tildada.

No se sinceramente si estoy ejecutando bien la app después de permitir los permisos o cual seria el error.

Busque de distintas formas pero el resultado es el mismo, agradecería su ayuda.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


    double longitud, latitud = 0;
    boolean Primeraubicacion = true;

    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    ImageView imageView;
    //   private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    Toast toast;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 metros
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minuto

    private int duracion_splash = 2300;
    private Timer timer;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                // verificamos la version de ANdroid que sea al menos la M para mostrar
                // el dialog de la solicitud de la camara
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) ;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }

        } else {



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    99);
        } else {
            locationStart();

        }

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            //-------------------SPLASH BARRA DE PROGRESO-------
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            final long intervalo = 45;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (i < 100){
                        progressBar.setProgress(i);
                        i++;
                    }else{
                        timer.cancel();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            },0,intervalo);

            return;
//--------------------------------------- FIN ------------------------------------------------//
        }



    }




    private void locationStart() {
        Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a locationStar");
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      // SplashActivity.Localizacion Local = new getContext().Localizacion();
        Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
        // Local.setMainActivity(this);
        assert mlocManager != null;
        final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!gpsEnabled) {
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
            Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a !gpsEnabled");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    99);
            return;
        } else{
            Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED");
        }

        /*toast = Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext(),
                "Por favor aguarde, ésto puede demorar unos segundos...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(requireContext());
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        Objects.requireNonNull(progressDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));*/
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, (LocationListener) Local);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,(LocationListener) Local);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a onRequestPermissionsResult");
        if (requestCode == 99) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationStart();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 99) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationStart();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationStart();
                return;
            }
            Log.e("camara", "Permiso aceptado de camara");
        }

    }

    /*public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                // List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1); //ESTO TRAE LA DIRECCIÓN CON ALTURA, CALLE, LOCALIDAD, PAIS
            /*  if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                    mensaje2.setText("Mi direccion es: \n"
                            + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                }*/
       /*         Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae Geocoder"+ list);
                Log.e("ya viene","Esta es la latitud: "+ loc.getLatitude()+" y esta es tu longitud "+loc.getLongitude());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }*/


    /* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
    public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
        MainActivity mainActivity;


        public  MainActivity getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }

        /*public void setMainActivity( com.example.christian.guatemayaapp.CheckIn mainActivity) {
            this.CheckIn = CheckIn;
        }*/


      /*  void setMainActivity(matiasl.nfctarjeta.nfctest.YavieneFragment mainActivity) {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a localizacion setMainActivity ");
            toast = Toast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext(),
                    "Procesando su ubicación actual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }*/



        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
            Log.e("ya viene","ingresa a localizacion onLocationChanged ");
            // debido a la deteccion de un cambio de ubicacion
            latitud= loc.getLatitude();
            Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae latitud ->"+latitud);
            longitud = loc.getLongitude();
            Log.e("ya viene","Esto trae longitud ->"+longitud);

            //CONSULTA SI ES LA PRIMERA UBICACION QUE TOMA EL GPS AL PRESIONAL EL BOTON YA VIENE Y LA ENVÍA, CASO CONTRARIO NO INGRESA
            if (Primeraubicacion){

                //CargarMapaGPS(latitud,longitud);

                Log.e("Primera ubicacion", "LATITUD: "+latitud+" LONGITUD: "+longitud);

                // enviarcoordenadasGET(Latitud,Longitud);
                Primeraubicacion = false;
            }
            //    MainActivity.this.setLocation(loc);
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
            //       mensaje1.setText("GPS Desactivado");
            Log.e("ya viene","EL GPS ESTÁ DESACTIVADO");

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
            //         mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
            Log.e("ya viene","EL GPS ESTÁ ACTIVADO");

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e("ya viene","onStatusChanged");
            switch (status) {

                case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                    break;
                case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                    Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hola, en que dispositivo estas probando?, a lo que veo es que te vas al MainActivity, tal vez aquí no tengas nada que mostrar por eso te sale en blanco.. te recomiendo también meter lo de los permisos en una clase así tendrás acceso a ella las veces que quieras sin repetir código

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hay en el MainActivity?